# Help troubleshooting a PoE circuit

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, ethernet, poe

After much ado I've designed a simple PoE addon board for a custom ESP32. However, when plugged in, the PoE light on the switch goes on for about half a second, and then goes back off. Seems like its trying to negotiate PoE but fails.

I have followed some examples i found online and tried to understand as much as i could from multiple sources when designing it.

It uses a Hanrun HR861153C magjack (Mode A & B) which includes diodes and directly provides V+ and V- to the board. The PoE chip is a TPS2378 (IEEE 802.3at) paired with a TPS54260 step-down converter to provide 5V (and later 3.3V using the ESP32 onboard regulator). I used [TI's tool](https://e2e.ti.com/cfs-file/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/196/TPS54x40_5F00_AND_5F00_TPS54x60_5F00_CALCTOOL_5F00_v1p1.xls) for calculating the SMPS values.

I have tried both a UniFi USW Flex (Mode A 802.3at) and a US 8 60W (Mode A 802.3af, i know its incompatible but anyway). Both are only at a fraction of their PoE load according to the UniFi console. Other PoE devices work fine on the same port.

Where should i begin to troubleshoot this? Never worked with PoE, just Arduinos and ESP32s. Is there any obvious mistake in the schematic?

Here is the schematic:

[image]

And the PCB:

[image]

Comment: A two layer circuit board would be inappropriate. Are you using matched differential impedances to your ethernet port? Your schematic doesn't look anything like what you have on your layout.

Comment: Ignoring your almost certainly problematic ethernet layout, and the not ideal step-down layout... CDB is Open-Drain, you have no pull-up, and the TPS54260 only provides a pull-up current source of 900nA... when that pin is NC, it'll "_probably be okay_", but It's very possible that's never going high... but I don't think that will cause negotiation to fail. Have you looked at the signals?

Comment: @Andyaka No, but that would be a later ethernet signal issue? Shouldnt cause issues with PoE? The schematic is only the PoE part, the W5500 and header are on a different sheet and i thought it wouldnt be relevant.

Comment: @Attie Isn't CDB an output that is supposed to drive the TSP54260? By your comment it sounds like the reverse? Someone else suggested the 47uF C20 and C21 could perhaps trigger inrush protection? Are they too large?

Comment: "_Isn't CDB an output_" ... yes, but it's "Open-Drain" (i.e: it can sink current, but not source it... pull the signal down, but not pull up)

Comment: @Attie I haven't probed it at all yet, where should i start?

Comment: @Attie So what you mean is that the TPS54260 may never be disabled? And "start immediately"?